# How to generate a reproducable private key from pass phrase using the openssl command?

Tags: openssl, private-key, passphrase

Invoking the following command multiple times seems to yield a different private key every time.

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private.pem -pass pass:papa-was-a-rolling-scone
```

What I would like is for the output to be reproducible. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. There is a random seed. Even without password protection, the key will not be the same.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question. That one's asking "Q: I've lost my private key that was generated from a random seed, can I get it back if I know the passphrase? (A: sorry, no)". This one seems to be asking "Q: Can I use a passphrase as the random seed so I can always regenerate the same key". AFAIK the answer is still no, but only because it's not supported in the software - I don't think there's any reason such a feature _couldn't_ be implemented. I don't think it's a great idea, which would go to explain why it _hasn't_ been implemented, assuming that is the case.

Comment: @psmears- apologies, i meant possible duplicate. Removed after a reread

Comment: Ooh! Maybe you could set a static seed by changing whichever rand openssl is using and maybe setting the clock. There are config settings for this. I'm going to play around with the idea, but I'm sure I'm overlooking some other factor like dhparams. Still, for whatever reason one would want to do this, I suggest not to. A lost key is a compromised key.